# Android re-ask denied permission

Tags: android, permissions

I am using following code to request permission.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(introduction_app.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(introduction_app.this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(introduction_app.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                111);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults[0] == -1){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            finishAffinity();
        else
            finish();
    }
}
```

But if user denied request then permission is not getting asked again. I am also not getting never ask again check box as other apps.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanx in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Once user denies for first time, then it will display "never ask again"

```
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(introduction_app.this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(introduction_app.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                            111);
                }
```